# Permissions for external HDD nextcloud container

Tags: containers, nextcloud

good day.

im trying to migrate my NC19 server to a container.

so far i can install the container and map a persistent drive to the host’s drive but when i try to use an external HDD i get the following erros on the log:

**Initializing nextcloud 19.0.2.2

rsync: chown “/var/www/html/data” failed: Operation not permitted (1)

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]**

this is more than likely a permissions issue, but when mounting the HDD as root and granting access to the external drive /media/ncd as root:root or as www-data:www-data i get the above error.

now, the external hdd file system is exfat (not sure if this will affect on the container).

any ideas how can i get past this?

im close to format my hdd as ext4 to see if this fixes it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

just got this fixed by changing the filesystem from ExFat to ext4