# shell : How to copy recursively also filenames that have specialchar

Tags: shell, copy, special-characters, filenames, cp

I'm using a simple script on ubuntu 20.04 to backup important folders on an external disk :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cp -r  /PROFILE PROFILE
cp -r /media/DATA DATA
```

It works fine except for some files whose filename contains special character : # | ? and '

- : happens for every screen capture (datetime) and when saving an email answer ("Re:")
- '#' occurs for every recorded sound ("title #12")
- ', | and ? occur mainly in saved html or emails
- also '*' (star) and '<' sometimes happen
- also when there is a space as the last char of a filename

The error is "cannot create standard file './DATA/Re: blahblah': Invalid argument" (translated from french langage error message). And the said file is not copied.

When i use rsync -avrq the same filenames also produce errors and arent copied, but rsync is a bit more verbose on errors :

- For '|' and ':' chars in file or foldernames rsync issues : « `rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/destinationfolder/filename with | or : " failed: Invalid argument (22)` »
- For other chars, rsync issues a plain : « `rsync: mkstemp "/destinationfolder/.filename with : inside.eml.UeByTF" failed: Invalid argument (22)` »
- in both case it issues « `*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***` » at the end of the containing folder

I once had (without the "quiet" option i think) this detail : « `rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]` »

How can I better use `cp -r` or `rsync` or another not-too-complex tool to also backup these files ? I've searched and couldnt find :-/

Could it be that this is related to an issue with my OS install rather than cp or rsync use ? This UBuntu 20.04 has been upgraded from 18.04 and sometimes tweaked.

[EDIT] Destination external HD partition is NTFS (says gparted) or "fuse" (says Nautilus / Properties). I see on [Permissions for external HDD nextcloud container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815217/permissions-for-external-hdd-nextcloud-container) that changing it to ext4 could bring a fix to the `(code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]` issue.

[EDIT] it looks like rsync uses a temporary file with '.' prefix and some times the issue is with this file and sometime it happens also when moving this file to final destination file (without .) :
`rsync: rename "/media/jluc/My Passport/SAVRSYNC/logo/.rubon1.ZpK66N" -> "logo/rubon1.": Invalid argument (22)`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: shellcheck advises to include the shebang so i did so in the code sample. That's all ("no issue detected")

Comment: @JLuc : I don't see in what respect your script should have problems with these filenames. What effect do you actually notice with those files?

Comment: @user1934428 the error message is "cp: cannot create standard file './DATA/Re: blahblah.eml': Invalid argument" (translated from french langage error message « cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard './DATA/Re: blahblah.eml': Argument invalide »)

Comment: Does the command work for the other files (i.e. those without "offending" characters)? What happens if you substitute `cp` by `rsync`? What does `cp --version` say?

Comment: @JLuc : I tried to recreate the problem by putting a file with the name `#:?|` in some directory, but I could do a `cp -r` of that  directory without problem. No error message on that particular file. Perhaps your `cp` is not `/usr/bin/cp`, but a shell script or function of the same name? What do you get if you do a `type cp` in your script, right before the copy commands?

Comment: @user1934428 "type cp" says "cp is /bin/cp" (translated from french "cp est /bin/cp")

Comment: And `--version`?

Comment: Oh i see there are still some errors with "rsync" : when there is * (star sign) or a < (lessthan sign) in the filename . I didnt mention these specialchars in the question because they're quite rare.

Comment: "cp --version" says : "cp (GNU coreutils) 8.30"

Comment: with rsync the error messages are more verbose
for '*' (star) in filename, its « rsync: mkstemp "destfolder/namewith*" failed : Invalid argument"
Note it's the destination file here

Comment: for rsync on a folder and file with < its :
  rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/media/jluc/My Passport/Inbox.sbd/Expéditions < 2017.sbd" failed:   Invalid argument (22)
  *** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
  rsync: mkstemp "/media/jluc/My Passport/Inbox.sbd/.Expéditions < 2017.msf.vtpxOj" failed: Invalid argument (22)
  rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]

Comment: @user1934428 AMOF rsync issues errors also for ':' :
 rsync: mkstemp "/media/jluc/My Passport/SAVRSYNC/REDACTION/.Re: French editing 2014.eml.pjinpH" failed: Invalid argument (22)

Comment: also errors when there is a space at the end of  a dirname :
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/media/jluc/My Passport/SAVRSYNC/REDACTION/REDACTION/DOCs/Oasis " failed: Invalid argument (22)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***

Comment: @JLuc : Now this gets even more mysterious, since spaces in a name are really permitted everywhere. I wonder whether there is something special with the file system you are using. I guess if you manually create a single file with such an offending character, you also get such error? For instance, when you do a `touch DATA/:` or a `touch PROFILE/#`, are you permitted to do this?

Comment: @user1934428 no problem with touch. I can `touch "PROFILE/#:'ENE"` and the file is created accordingly with this name.
I have some issues with CTRL+SHIFT keyboard modifier on this machine and it could be that the OS is not perfectly ok. Hence, I wish to install ubuntu 20.10 from scratch... and that's why i want a thorough backup... but maybe the system realy is not OK and it would explain these abnormal behaviours...

Comment: If you can **touch** is, the next question is whether you can manually **cp** a _single_ offending file, i.e. without the `-r` option.  Ah, and just for completeness: Are `/media/DATA` and `DATA` on the same file system?

Comment: @user1934428 i'm not sure to understand your question : DATA actualy is /media/DATA

Comment: I had some THUNDERBIRD folders with specialchars. I renamed them (with TB UI) so as to not have these specialchars. Everything was fine IN thunderbird but when backuping the profile, there were still issues with these with-specialchars folders : that's because TB could create the new clean-name folders and move their mail content there, but could not delete the old with-specialchar-named folders. Their content was only empty TB files though (the mails had been moved). I later could delete these folders with nautilus UI (select + DEL key).

Comment: @user1934428 within /PROFILE, i tried « cp "#:<>'ENE" /media/jluc/Elements » and got the following error message « cp: impossible de créer le fichier standard '/media/jluc/Elements/#:<>'\''ENE': Argument invalide »

Comment: I created an ext4 partition and it doesnt produces errors anymore when copying to it.
It's probably not realy the ideal solution, but it is a good solution for me (because 
fixing it for NTFS destinations would probably require long and too complex investigating ...)
Thanks @user1934428 for caring

Comment: NTFS is a drag ...... I'm always using ext4, but I had not expected that they behave THAT strangely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found to cp files with specialchar in their name is to copy them to an EXT4 partition instead of NTFS.

So i reduced the NTFS external HD partition (it required the whole night to do so), created an EXT4 partition (labelled "EXT4ELEM") in the spare space and used it to backup my files : no more errors.

« cp "#:<>'ENE" /media/jluc/EXT4ELEM » is OK.

(inspiration found here : [Permissions for external HDD nextcloud container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815217/permissions-for-external-hdd-nextcloud-container))